# Flutter IOS Unable to compile code. Takes too long

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, throw

Bellow I have attached the issue.
Unlike other people who have gotten this issue and their code still ran, my code wont even run. 
Please offer any suggestions and help. Thank You!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the `flutter doctor` output?

Answer (score 0):

Switch your channel to dev than run

> flutter upgrade

Its work for me .